# ABS formula within a QUERY in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, absolute, google-query-language

With the following Query:
=QUERY(Transactions!$A$2:$N$300;"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, K, L, M, N")

I am trying to get the results from F and N to be absolute values while leaving the rest as is and I am having issues with the syntax of this line.

I tried a few options by adding {} and \ in the formula but I still keep getting a parsing error. It is probably an easy fix but I just do not know how to go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ABS()` is not recognized as `QUERY()` aggregation function. So, use `ABS()` for those columns (you want absolute value) then merge using either array notation `{...}` or using `HSTACK()` function. Try-

```
=QUERY({A:C,INDEX(ABS(D:E))},"select *")
```

Using `HSTACK()` function.

```
=QUERY(HSTACK(A:C,INDEX(ABS(D:E))),"select *")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! The normal query syntax with the {...} was returning a #VALUE error but the HSTACK formula is working perfectly!

Comment: Glad to know! If it works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the thread as solved.